# Grabbing values from a different tables and appending to jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append

I am using two tables, one for product name and one for product image path...
I am able to grab the image path and add images to the html dynamically. It works fine.

The problem is that when I want to add the title of image on hover which is a div class on top
of image, I change the title on hover div using  jQuery's  each function, the title gets concatenated 
rather than added to the particular image.

Here is my code to append the images from table path..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mainContentPlaceholder_productPathGridView').hide(); //Hides ImagePath Gridview

        var arr = []; //Creates an Array Path Arr
        $("#mainContentPlaceholder_productPathGridView td").each(function () {  //Loops through GridView Td (Table Columns)
            arr.push($(this).text());
        });

        // Starts adding Images to the  Gallery 
        $.each(arr, function (index, imageLocation) {
            $(".megafolio-container").append('<div class="mega-entry jeans cat-all" data-src="' + imageLocation + '"' + 'data-width="395" data-height="507"><div class="mega-hover"><div class="mega-hovertitle"><h2 class="productNameTitle"></h2><a class="shopButton" href="itemDetails.aspx">Details</a></div></div></div>'); //Apended New  Values
        });

    });
</script>
```

And here is my added code to append the Ids:

```
<!-- Getting Product Names-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mainContentPlaceholder_productNameGridView').hide(); //Hides ImagePath Gridview

        var arr2 = []; //Creates an Array Path Arr
        $("#mainContentPlaceholder_productNameGridView td").each(function () {  //Loops through GridView Td (Table Columns)
            arr2.push($(this).text());
        });

        // Starts adding Images to the  Gallery 
        $.each(arr2, function (index, productname) {
         //   alert(productname);
           $(".productNameTitle").text(productname); //Apended New Name
        });
        });
</script>
```

Now the problem exists as the ids are concatenated on every div..

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong..why don't u use  one loop instead of two.. you are creating teo different array arr,arr2 and looping thorough it...to display the same text..

try this

```
$("#mainContentPlaceholder_productNameGridView td").each(function () {  //Loops through GridView Td (Table Columns)
        $(".megafolio-container").append('<div class="mega-entry jeans cat-all" data-src="' + $(this).text() + '"' + 'data-width="395" data-height="507"><div class="mega-hover"><div class="mega-hovertitle"><h2 class="productNameTitle"></h2><a class="shopButton" href="itemDetails.aspx">Details</a></div></div></div>'); //Apended New  Values
        $(".productNameTitle").text($(this).text());
    });
```

Comment: its not working.i want image path from one table and name path from another, the image path appending to html works fine but on name path, the names are concatenated , i am using the same code as for appending the image path. In div called productNameTitle the name should be appended. its appending but all the names are concatenated.. Please help . thanks

Comment: ok i tried the .html() method to change but only the last itemname which i set to 11 is shown in every div... please help.

Comment: try this...$(".productNameTitle").text('<p>'+productname+'</p>');.. have to see your HTML code to help you..

Comment: Nope, still displays 11 in each div, is it because i am using the numbers rather than name ? i tried alert to check for values, they are comming fine. but i dont know why it dosen't change in correct format.. maybe because the main container divs are also dynamically generated? can u help me, this is very important for my project. thanks